# Ender 3 Pro not interpreting G-code correctly?

Tags: creality-ender-3, g-code

I have an Ender 3 Pro and I have been able to get it to work quite well, I installed a 0.8 mm nozzle to try the Vase mode in Cura. I re-leveled the bed and when I tried to print, I got some very strange behavior.

When it starts the "purge line" along the side of the bed, the Z-axis is too high and instead of going down the left side and back up, it will go down the left side and then from left to right along the back edge and then stop and then just extrude filament. If I look at the beginning portion of the G-code it doesn't look any different than the G-Code for the other models I have printed except for in the initialization script it set the Layer height and Min Z to 0.32 instead of 0.2 and the code for drawing the first 2 purge lines is identical. I tried printing an older file that worked correctly and I got the same results where it went along the left side then along the back side and stopped and just extruded filament.

It seems like something in the printer went wonky? What would cause this and what is the fix? A reset of some sort? And how is that accomplished?

Comment: what *is* the start Gcode? We can't tell you if that is excepted with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being something with the printer, I powered it down, let it set a few minutes and then powered it up and it printed correctly. Is there a way to "reset" it without the power cycle, and is this something common? Thanks for the response!

Comment: yes, there are reset commands, no, a hard-reset works better - as to be able to send a reset command you need to connect the printer to a terminal PC, and that means you reset the printer by connecting it...

Comment: Is this something that is a common occurrence? Is there something that might have caused this?

Comment: I don'T know what might have caused it, but regular shutdowns are a safety measure and at the same time reset the printer.